# Existence of positive solutions of a linear PDE on closed manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I was wondering is there a sufficient condition (or sufficient and necessary condition) for the existence of positive solutions of the following linear PDE on a closed manifold $(M, g)$,

\begin{equation*}
\Delta u +\nabla u\nabla f +hu=0.
\end{equation*}
where $f, h\in C^{\infty}(M)$.

I got some necessary conditions using the Stokes formula, but I couldn't find a statement for sufficient condition, or sufficient and necessary condition. Thank you very much for any suggestions.

Comment: There is of course the trivial sufficient condition $h=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a full answer, but some observations.

First, I'm assuming $M$ is compact, orientable, etc. $h$ attains its maximum $C$ somewhere on $M$, so that $k(q) = C - h(q)$ is nonnegative.

Your PDE then becomes the eigenvalue problem
$$Lu = Cu$$
where
$$L = -e^{-f}\nabla \cdot \left(e^f \nabla u\right) + k u$$
is a positive elliptic operator on $M$. For given $f$ and $k$, this equation will have nontrivial solutions only for countably many positive values of $C$, and nonnegative solutions $u$ if and only if $C$ is the least eigenvalue of $L$.

I have no idea how to go about formulating a sufficient condition for $C$ being that eigenvalue, though.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you tell me any reference on what you said?

Comment: In the simple case, i.e., $f=$constant, it seems the problem reduces to \begin{equation} \inf_{\|u\|_{L^2}=1}\int_M |\nabla u|^2+hu^2. \end{equation} If $h\geq 0$, then we are done. If $h$ is not nonnegative but satisfies $\int_Mh>0$, could we still prove that the infimum is nonnegative?